# Cómo comvertir un número humanizado a Flotante

Tags: typescript

Estoy necesitando convertir un string que contiene un numero humanizado a flotante

> Aclaración se suele decir que un numero esta humanizado cuando se
>   escribe de una forma la cual lo hace  mas legible por las personas en
>   resumen de la siguiente forma `55.445,88`

Por ejemplo quiero convertir `'34.233,56'` a `34233.56` el problema es que, en mi pais se usa la coma para separar los decimales y el punto para separar los miles por lo que no puedo usar directamente `parseFloat`, escribí una pequeña función pero quisiera ver si hay una forma mas practica.

```
private toNumber(number: any): number {
    if (typeof number === 'string') {
        return parseFloat(number.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.').replace(/(\$|%| )/g, ''));
    } else {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: porque numero "humanizado" cuando puedes declarar el input numerico agregandole formato?

Comment: Estoy usando [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask) el cual por desgracia no soporta tipo number, ademas te convierte, humaniza el valor y yo lo necesito como flotante para poder trabajarlo ya que tengo que sumar esos valores.

Comment: deberias agregarlo a la pregunta leyendo un poco la libreria encontre esto https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons#createnumbermask

Comment: usas typescript con que ? angular? REACT? jQuery?

Comment: Tal vez lo puedas convertir más convenientemente del lado del servidor y no en javascript. Número "humanizado" tiene un nombre formal e incluye formato de fechas y moneda, entre otras cosas. El proceso se conoce como "internacionalización y localización", también abreviados como i18n y L10N por el número de letras entre la inicial y la última. Javascript "localiza" números formateándolos en cadenas pero no al revés sin la ayuda de una librería adicional.